# Enable Button When Any Checkbox Values Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a page with multiple checkboxes in varying states (checked or unchecked) . I'm trying to enable a button as soon as any of the checkbox values change state.

Here is my code so far but it doesn't seem to work properly yet:

```js
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
    
checkboxes.change(function(){
    $('#saveChanges').prop('enabled', true);
});
```

Comment: so what is the problem? do you mean when at least one of the checkbox is checked?

Comment: `$('#saveChanges').prop('disabled', false);`

Comment: Why aren't you posting a MCVE?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tbt1n236/1/ ?

Comment: I don't understand the question - could you try to be more specific on your desired outcome

Comment: do u want to enable the button if any one of the checkbox if checked???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {


        $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {

            $('#saveChanges').prop('disabled', false);

        });

 });  
</script>
</head>
<body>


  <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<button id="saveChanges" disabled>Save</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.   I need to enable the button if any of the checkboxes change.  https://jsfiddle.net/Lgop8aqp/

Comment: @kernelpanic You forgot to add JQuery in the jsfiddle--> [https://jsfiddle.net/Lgop8aqp/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgop8aqp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try, where submit button would be..

> ```
> <input type="submit" value="Do thing" disabled>
> ```

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");
checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="true">
<button type="submit" id="confirmButton">BUTTON</button>

var checkboxes = $('.myCheckBox');

checkboxes.on('change', function () 
{
    $('#confirmButton').prop('disabled', !checkboxes.filter(':checked').length);
}).trigger('change');
```